# Imprimir caracteres até determinada letra e incluir quebra de linha ao final

Tags: python

> Crie um programa que receba como entrada um caractere alfabético maiúsculo e exiba a sequência do alfabeto maiúsculo de 'A' até o caractere lido. O programa deverá repetir o procedimento até que seja dado como entrada o caractere 'F'.

**Formato de entrada**

Um caractere alfabético maiúsculo [ 'A' .. 'Z' ].

```
Z
B
C
W
E
F
```

**Formato de saída**

Para cada caractere dado como entrada, uma linha com a sequência alfabética maiúscula de 'A' até o caractere informado, separados por um espaço.

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
A B 
A B C 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W 
A B C D E
```

Código criado desde então, abaixo:

```
letra = input()
letra = ord(letra)

while letra != 70:
    for i in range(65,letra+1):
        print(chr(i),end=' ')
    letra = input()
    letra = ord(letra)
```

Até funciona, mas não dá a saída esperada com a quebra de linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, [elimine as repetições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/112052) do seu código. Não tem porque chamar [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) antes do `while` e depois dentro dele. Faça-o apenas uma vez e use-o dentro do laço principal. Na verdade, como o programa deve aceitar somente uma letra de "A" a "Z", você pode criar uma função para fazer essa validação separadamente:

```
def ler_letra():
    while True:
        letra = input()
        if len(letra) == 1 and 'A' <= letra <= 'Z':
            return letra
        else: print('Digite uma letra de A a Z')

while True:
    letra = ler_letra()
    if letra == 'F':
        break
    print(' '.join(chr(i) for i in range(65, ord(letra) + 1)))
```

A função `ler_letra` verifica se o que foi digitado é de fato uma letra de "A" a "Z". Se não for, ele pede que seja digitado novamente, e só retorna quando for digitado (`while True` cria um *loop* infinito que vai se repetindo até que seja digitado uma letra válida, e só neste caso sai da função com `return`). É importante verificar isso, pois se for digitada uma string com mais de um caractere, [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) dará erro (e se não for uma letra, nem adianta prosseguir com o algoritmo).

Depois eu faço um *loop* infinito que vai lendo a letra e verifica se é "F" (e se for, o `break` interrompe esse *loop*). Se não for "F", imprime as letras e o *loop* continua.

Para imprimir, usei [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para juntar as letras, separando-as com espaço. Para gerar as letras, usei uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052). Com isso as letras são impressas com um espaço entre elas, e a quebra de linha já é adicionada no final.

Mas claro que você também pode usar seu *loop* adicionando um `print()` depois do `for`, como sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449909/112052) - a diferença é que ao usar `end=' '`, um espaço extra é adicionado no final, e isso pode ou não fazer diferença (para um exercício talvez não faça, mas há casos em que faz - por exemplo, se a saída de um programa é lida por outro, um espaço a mais ou a menos pode fazer diferença no processamento - pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas programação é cheia desses detalhes e é importante acostumar-se com eles desde já).

---

Mas claro que, se não precisar validar que o valor digitado é uma letra (por ser um exercício, *pode ser* que todas as entradas sejam válidas, visto que não foi nem pedido para validar), e se o espaço a mais no final das linhas não fizer diferença, aí poderia ser simplesmente:

```
while True:
    letra = input()
    if letra == 'F':
        break
    for i in range(65, ord(letra) + 1):
        print(chr(i), end=' ')
    print()
```

Repare que não precisa pedir o `input` antes do *loop*. Basta fazer o `while True` (que se repete "indefinidamente"), e interrompê-lo se for digitado "F".

---

Uma solução mais genérica seria ter uma lista de letras válidas, e ao imprimir você cria uma sub-lista que vai até o índice da letra indicada:

```
def ler_letra(letras_validas):
    while True:
        letra = input()
        if letra in letras_validas:
            return letra
        else: print('Digite uma letra válida')

from string import ascii_uppercase
maiusculas = list(ascii_uppercase)

while True:
    letra = ler_letra(maiusculas)
    if letra == 'F':
        break
    print(' '.join(maiusculas[:maiusculas.index(letra) + 1]))
```

Nesse caso eu usei [`ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase), que já tem todas as letras maiúsculas de A a Z em ordem, mas o código acima pode ser usado para qualquer lista de caracteres que você quiser, deixando o código um pouco mais genérico (já que as soluções anteriores são específicas para as letras de A a Z).

Por isso não preciso mais testar se o tamanho da string digitada é 1, pois agora é suficiente verificar se ela está na lista (aliás, agora a lista pode conter strings de tamanhos variados que funcionará da mesma forma).

Answer (score 1):

Para realiza a quebra de linha, basta adicionar um `print()` vazio antes de obter a entrada do usuário ou então utilizar o caractere especial `"\n"` dentro da função `input()`.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
letra = input()
letra = ord(letra)

while letra != 70:

    for i in range(65, letra + 1):
        print(chr(i), end = ' ')
    print()

    letra = input()
    letra = ord(letra)
```

Há uma forma mais bonita e idiomática de realizar a impressão das letras que seria criar uma lista com os caracteres e depois desconstruí-la na chamada do `print()`. Dessa forma, não será necessário especificar o espaçamento no final da impressão.

```
chars = [chr(id_) for id_ in range(65, char + 1)]
print(*chars)
```

Há também um outro problema no seu código, que não gera nenhum erro, mas talvez não seja algo que você gostaria que acontecesse. Como o objetivo do programa é receber e mostrar letras maiúsculas, o que aconteceria se o usuário inserisse uma letra minúscula ?

A resposta é que o programa iria imprimir todas as letras maiúsculas e só iria parar até chegar na letra minúscula. Logo, você pode utilizar o método `upper()` para transformar a entrada do usuário em maiúsculo.

Abaixo está o código refatorado que eu fiz:

```
def show_chars(char):
    chars = [chr(id_) for id_ in range(65, char + 1)]
    print(*chars)

while True:
    char = ord(input("Letra: ").upper())
    if char == 70: break
    show_chars(char)
```

Comment: Forma mais bonita não, forma idiomática ou se quiser ser informal ao comentar use forma pythônica.

Comment: Ei Augusto, por falar em forma idiomática eu tenho uma dúvida. É correto utilizar um código do `if` na mesma linha assim como eu fiz na resposta ou é melhor sempre colocar o código em baixo indentado ?

Comment: Jean, eu não sou purista a esse ponto, eu uso da forma que fez. Quem poderia lhe responder melhor é o pessoal da area acadêmica ou pessoal mais compromissado com a parte teórica. Eu tenho mitos vícios de CPD, na produção muitas vezes tomamos atalhos para poupar tempo e que o pessoal da acadêmia as me chama a atenção em minhas respostas.